# How can I pass a variable into an ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-include src="itemG.html"></div>
</div>
```

then in itemG.html I have:

```
<img src="{{item.image}}">
```

How can I get my ng-repeat to print out all of the images?

Comment: in your `itemG.html` file... is the only thing in there the one `<img />` tag?

Comment: There is a lot more html in the file but I'm only using the item.image out of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 potential problems in the code...

`src="itemG.html"` needs an extra pair of single quotes like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-include="'itemG.html'"></div>
</div>
```

And the `img` tag is missing a closing `"`:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.image}}">
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7IUs7WPdUYkfVVKtBN1m?p=preview

Comment: this is incorrect. using the single quotes inside the regular `src` attribute will only work for non-expressions. This means nothing that angular needs to bind to as well, which is the case here.  You **have** to use `{{ }}` expression to bind, which means you also have to use `ng-src` instead.

Comment: This is correct according to Angular docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)... angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"; I also had this tested in a plunker as well but didn't post the link. I can recreate it if required. Rereading the docs I think the more correct form is `<div ng-include="'itemG.html'"></div>`, but the single quotes are still okay.

Comment: lol... actually we're both right, and wrong, in our own ways.  Look at what's in his .html file. I knew there was a reason I was thinking he was using a binding expression, just got all caught up in things and forgot the string *was* a string constant (which is why the quotes work)

Comment: removed my dv as a result. Misread it as a evaluation instead of a string.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what this comes down to is that the browser will interpret what inside the src attribute literally, until angular comes along to replace it. If you have a string constant, you can use single quotes inside the `src="'myurl.html'"`, but if you have a value that needs to be bound by angular, you have to use `ng-src` and the expression syntax of `{{ }}`

You also need to bind a model to your template file itself. It's not going to pick up the bindings from your repeater without some help from either the ng-include event directives, or it's own model/controller/directive.  There are too many different ways to demonstrate that, and it's also relevant on what markup is in your template file, which I can't say.

However, if the `img` tag is the only thing in that file, then instead of the file, I'd just do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <img ng-src="item.image" />
</div>
```

Since you're inside a repeat, it's already being included, making the `ng-include` redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In principal code

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <ng-include src="itemG.html" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="i=item"><ng-include>
</div>
```

then in itemG.html I have:

```
<img src="{{i.image}}">
```